# CountDownTimer onTick() can't update a member of class

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I update a field inside CountDownTimer in onTick() method. However, the field is always 0. Do you have an idea what is causing a problem?

```
public class Counter {

    private static final long SECOND_MS = 1000;
    private static final long MINUTE_MS = 60 * SECOND_MS;
    private static final long TOTAL_TIME_MS = 5 * MINUTE_MS;

    public long mSecondsSinceLastPick;

    public long getSecondsSinceLastSchedulerStarted() {
        Timber.d( String.format("get mSecondsSinceLastPick = %s", mSecondsSinceLastPick) );
        return mSecondsSinceLastPick;
    }


    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(TOTAL_TIME_MS, SECOND_MS) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Timber.d( String.format("onTick mSecondsSinceLastPick = %s", mSecondsSinceLastPick) );
            mSecondsSinceLastPick = (TOTAL_TIME_MS - millisUntilFinished) / SECOND_MS;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
        }
    };

public void startCounting() {
    mCountDownTimer.start();
}
}
```

[EDITED]
Log output looks like

```
06-19 15:42:57.293 9994-9994/com.nav.survey D/GroundTruthReminderManager:38: onTick mSecondsSinceLastPick = 4
06-19 15:42:58.293 9994-9994/com.nav.survey D/GroundTruthReminderManager:38: onTick mSecondsSinceLastPick = 5
06-19 15:42:59.299 9994-9994/com.nav.survey D/GroundTruthReminderManager:38: onTick mSecondsSinceLastPick = 6
06-19 15:43:00.320 9994-9994/com.nav.survey D/GroundTruthReminderManager:38: onTick mSecondsSinceLastPick = 7
06-19 15:43:01.321 9994-9994/com.nav.survey D/GroundTruthReminderManager:38: onTick mSecondsSinceLastPick = 8
06-19 15:43:01.507 9994-9994/com.nav.survey D/GroundTruthReminderManager:22: get mSecondsSinceLastPick = 0
06-19 15:43:02.322 9994-9994/com.nav.survey D/GroundTruthReminderManager:38: onTick mSecondsSinceLastPick = 9
06-19 15:43:03.324 9994-9994/com.nav.survey D/GroundTruthReminderManager:38: onTick mSecondsSinceLastPick = 10
06-19 15:43:04.325 9994-9994/com.nav.survey D/GroundTruthReminderManager:38: onTick mSecondsSinceLastPick = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you dont start the timer

```
 mCountDownTimer.start();
```

or

```
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(TOTAL_TIME_MS, SECOND_MS) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Timber.d( String.format("onTick mSecondsSinceLastPick = %s", mSecondsSinceLastPick) );
        mSecondsSinceLastPick = (TOTAL_TIME_MS - millisUntilFinished) / SECOND_MS;
    }

    public void onFinish() {
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: I start, but forgot to copy this code. Generally speaking, when I log it inside onTick(), everything is displayed correctly. When I log the field in getter, it's always 0.

Comment: When are you getting it? Do you only get it once?

Comment: I'm calling getter several times during counting. I added logs.

Comment: You must be getting it before the onTick or after, please add the code to get it

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with creating my counter. I use Dagger @Singleton annotation to provide Counter, however, anyway 2 instances of Counter were created and it caused a problem.